# How to reference an element in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to reference an element that is located in a child component. I am using `document.getElementById` from its parent component, and it works good, but I have heard that it is better practice to use `ref`. Is this true? If so, how is that done?

**Parent (container) component:**

```
import CanvasView from '../view/CanvasView'

export default class CanvasContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas')
    //DO SOMETHING WITH c
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <CanvasView />
    )
  }
}
```

**Child (presentation) component:**

```
export default const CanvasView = () => (
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
)
```

Comment: With stateless components you can not use `refs`, however you can it with `React.Component` and with `React.createClass` like so - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44464/

Comment: Ah, ok. Do you recommend using `React.Component` and then use `ref`, instead of a stateless component, with `getElementById` in the parent component?

Comment: using `getElementById` with React it is bad practices...

Comment: Okey, thanks. So "the react way" of using `id` is to use  `React.Component` together with `refs` (and abandon the stateless component)?

Answer (score 0):

Using React's lifecycle events is a bit messy, querying the DOM for elements is bad practice as well. Also , since the child components have their own lifecycle it's tricky to handle these situations. Furthermore, you can't access child `refs` as the parent components don't have access to the children `refs`. You may pass a callback function though, and pass the selected child element as a reference to the parent component.

```
var CanvasView = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Child component did mount, do your stuff')
    this.props.callback(this.exampleRef)
  },
    render: function(){
    return(<div ref={(ref) => this.exampleRef = ref}>Foo</div>)
  }
});

var CanvasContainer = React.createClass({
    doSomethingWithChild(child){
    console.log('Parent component')
    child.style.backgroundColor='red';
  },
  render: function(){
    return(<CanvasView callback={(e) => this.doSomethingWithChild(e)}/>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<CanvasContainer/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nwwzyttt/2/